# In WKWebView Pressing Return Key Dismisses Keyboard

Tags: ios, keyboard, wkwebview, rte, froala

I'm working on implementing the Froala Editor in WKWebView to provide Rich Text Editing for our app. It appears that the default behavior is for the return key to dismiss the keyboard firing UIKeyboardWillHideNotification etc ... The keyboard is immediately redisplayed so that it doesn't disappear from the user's perspective.  However, the code to manage the scrolling the webview out of the way of keyboard is executed causing a bit of flashing and view movements.

Is there a way to prevent the return key from dismissing the keyboard as was the behavior in UIWebView?

Comment: Based on the response I received from Stefan Neclulai at Froala.  This behavior is currently a work around they have in place to respond to an iOS browser problem.

Answer (score 0):

You usually have to proactively dismiss the keyboard- so unless you are calling something in your code such as [webView endEditing:YES]; It's confusing why the keyboard is hiding on its own.

There was apparently a Froala bug prior to 2.1.0 related to dismissing the keyboard, maybe that's it?

Comment: Using Froala 2.1.0 and no [webView endEditing: YES] calls in the native code.